# Want to update MongoDB with data that does not include objects that include the paid: true key/value

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Good Evening,
I am using the MERN stack to create an application. I am using the Stripe API to gather invoices and save some information about the invoice in MongoDB. Right now I have a function that updates my DB with any object that does not exist and I have a delete function that deletes any documents in my DB that have the paid: true. when an invoice is paid Stripe marks it paid, when its paid I want to delete it from my DB. What happens now is that I delete it and then update function runs and just puts it right back.

The data in my DB and from stripe are an array of objects:

```
DB Sample:
[
 {
  Id: String,
  created: Number,
  customer_email: String,
  customer_name: String,
  due_date: Number,
  hosted_invoice_url: String,
  paid: Boolean
 }
]
```

Codebase functions:

```js
// Update and store function

  async function saveInvoice(stripeInvoice) {

      const condition = {id: stripeInvoice.id};
      const query = { 
          id: stripeInvoice.id,
          created: stripeInvoice.created,
          customer_email: stripeInvoice.customer_email,
          customer_name: stripeInvoice.customer_name,
          due_date: stripeInvoice.due_date,
          hosted_invoice_url: stripeInvoice.hosted_invoice_url,
          paid: stripeInvoice.paid,
        };
      const options = { upsert: true };
       
    const update = await InvoiceModel.updateMany(condition, query, options).catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
    if(update.nModified > 0 ) {
      console.log('Number of Invoices added or updated to DB:', update.nModified)
    }
    

  }

// Find common ID
  function findCommoneID(stripeInvoice, DBInvoices) {
 
    var isSame = true;

    if(DBInvoices.length <= 0 || stripeInvoice.length <= 0) {

      console.log('An Error has occured with Database or Stripe Data')
      return isSame = false;

    } else {
      stripeInvoice.forEach((StripeElement) => {
      
        DBInvoices.forEach((DBElement) => {
          
          
            if(StripeElement.id !== DBElement.id) {
              saveInvoice(StripeElement, DBElement);
              isSame = false;
            } 
        })
      });
    }
    console.log('IDS match')
    return isSame;
}

// Delete Function
async function deletePaidInvoicesFromDB(dbInvoices) {

    for(let i = 0; i < dbInvoices.length; i++) {
      if(dbInvoices[i].paid === true ) {
        console.log(dbInvoices[i].id);
        const deletedInvoices = await InvoiceModel.deleteMany({paid: true});
        console.log(deletedInvoices.deletedCount)
        break;
      }
      
    }
    

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The save function takes in the data gathered from the findCommonId() function and if the id doesn't exist it adds the stripe object to the DB.

```js
// Save Function
  async function saveInvoice(stripeInvoice) {

    if(stripeInvoice.paid === true) {
      return;
    } else {

      const condition = {id: stripeInvoice.id};
      const query = { 
          id: stripeInvoice.id,
          amount_due: stripeInvoice.amount_due,
          created: stripeInvoice.created,
          customer_email: stripeInvoice.customer_email,
          customer_name: stripeInvoice.customer_name,
          due_date: stripeInvoice.due_date,
          hosted_invoice_url: stripeInvoice.hosted_invoice_url,
          paid: stripeInvoice.paid,
        };
      const options = { upsert: true };
       
    const update = await InvoiceModel.updateMany(condition, query, options).catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
    if(update.nModified > 0 ) {
      console.log('Number of Invoices added or updated to DB:', update.nModified)
    }
    }
  }
  
  
  // findCommoneId
  
     function findCommoneID(stripeInvoice, DBInvoices) {
 
    

    if(DBInvoices.length <= 0 || stripeInvoice.length <= 0) {

      InvoiceModel.create(stripeInvoice, () => {console.log('Invoices saved to database')});
      console.log('An Error has occured with Database or Stripe Data')
      
      stripeInvoice.forEach((StripeElement) => {
        if(StripeElement.paid === true) {
          return;
        } 
      })
      stripeInvoice.forEach((StripeElement) => {
      
        DBInvoices.forEach((DBElement) => {
          
          
            if(StripeElement.id !== DBElement.id) {
              saveInvoice(StripeElement);
              
            } 
        })
      });
    }
    console.log('IDS match')
}
```